# Toggling "Allow Reparenting" on Master Detail record

Tags: master-detail

I have a master detail relationship that does not currently allow re-parenting.  I also have some detail records that were created on the wrong parent.  Will I be causing any problems in my instance if I turn "Allow re-parenting" on in order to get the problems corrected and turn it off once the problems are fixed?

I'm concerned that doing this may cause a lot of work behind the scenes.  There are 3 million records of this type, but I'll only be reparenting a handful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe it will have any effect other than allowing you to do it when on. If you have any concerns I would test it out in a partial or full sandbox first.

I know we have changed this value for one of our managed packages and deployed without any ill effects at all.